# How to use Django parsley with crispy form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am a beginner in Django crispy form and Django parsley,I want to know how to add data-validate = 'parsley' in the form tag.

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

my form.py consist of the following code.I am using Crispy form.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
            Describes how to render the form in the template.
        '''
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # This is to handle department permissions for department
        self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.all()
        # This is to handle department level permissions for batches
        self.fields['batch'].queryset = Batches.objects.all()
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'add_student_details'
        self.helper.form_class = 'ajax-student-create-form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'students_add_new_student'
        #self.helper.attrs = {'data-parsley-validate'}
        self.helper.html5_required = True
```

I need the form tag should be like this,

```
<form data-validate="parsley" method="post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [crispy FormHelper docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html):

> **attrs**
>
> Added in 1.2.0, a dictionary to set any kind of form attributes. Underscores in keys are translated into hyphens. The recommended way when you need to set several form attributes in order to keep your helper tidy:
>
> `{'id': 'form-id', 'data_id': '/whatever'}`
>
> `<form id="form-id" data-id="/whatever" ...>`

In your should be code:

```
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.attrs = {'data-validate':'parsley'}
```